# React native : What should be the local database if I am using mongodb stitch

Tags: react-native, mongodb-stitch

I am trying to set up react native app with MongoDB stitch
So what should be the local database that needs to be used? 
Where can I find an application which uses MongoDB stitch + react-native+ local database?

I saw the MongoDB documentation and todo app - But I did not quite get what is local database and how it is stored locally